# Two folders with controllers MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to store controller for Admin views in Administration folder but i dont know how i can connect views from Admin with Controllers in Administration.

[image]

```
             app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
               endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           });
```

These are the default endpoints, maybe I need to change something here. Maybe someone will show me what to read or correct to solve the problem.

Comment: Why not just use Areas?

Comment: Areas are great for this. You could also maybe add the Administration folder within the Controllers folder? That way controllers are all in one location separated by folders. In general though, I believe you can connect the views that are within your Admin folder with any controller essentially. EX: within the Category controller, on one of your action methods, specify the exact name of the View you want: return View("ViewName");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> store controller for Admin views in Administration folder but i dont know how i can connect views from Admin with Controllers in Administration

In [doc about "View discovery"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#view-discovery), you would find:

*The default behavior of the View method (return View();) is to return a view with the same name as the action method from which it's called.*

*First, the runtime looks in the `Views/[ControllerName]` folder for the view. If it doesn't find a matching view there, it searches the Shared folder for the view.*

If you'd like to return view (view files are stored under `Views/Admin` folder) within `CategoryController` action(s), you can provide a view file path instead of a view name, like below.

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Views/Admin/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

Besides, as @Nikki9696 and @Filipe mentioned, [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0) provide a way to organize related functionality into smaller functional groups, you can try to put administration related functionality as a separate area.